# Does the "x questions with activity" feature honor ignored/favorite tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I'm not sure if the new "x questions with activity" feature does honor the ignored/favorite tags, because *sometimes* I get a notification for questions which should be ignored, but are not marked as such. Additionally, the ignored/favorite-tags-styles are not applied to the loaded question.

[image: Showing Super User with the notification.]
[image: Showing Super User after clicking that notification.]

Though, I'm unable to reliably reproduce that. So, here comes the question, does that new feature honor my tag-settings, and if not, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignored preferences will be really be ignored in the realtime active tab update.  This will be in the next build.