# Ignored tags filter doesn't run when loading new questions

Tags: bug, ignored-tags

As with many people, I'm trying to avoid spoilers for the new *Star Wars* movie; not an easy task, since my main site is Science Fiction & Fantasy. Like a good little <s>frog</s> boy, I've added our [the-force-awakens] tag to my Ignore list. So for the most part, I'm golden.

However, sometimes they slip through; case in point, when I load more questions via the "*x* questions with new activity" AJAX call; the question list is updated, but the question is still there:

[image]

Since [tag filtering is done on the client side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63193/how-is-ignored-tags-interesting-tags-implemented), it doesn't seem like there's a technical reason not to run the filtering script after the AJAX call completes.

Now that I've gone and written all this, I noticed that this [was apparently done in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124505/does-the-x-questions-with-activity-feature-honor-ignored-favorite-tags), so I guess this is a bug.